# Trigger - Error "expecting right square bracket, found 'in' "

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, compile-error

Why Do I get this error in the below code?

**Error**

> expecting right square bracket, found 'in'

**Code**

```
trigger ProposalTriggerTest on Proposal__Proposal__c (after update) {
    try{
        list < Proposal__Proposal__c > updateList  =  new list < Proposal__Proposal__c > (); 
        list < Proposal__Proposal__c > currentProposalList  =   [ Select id , (Select LineType__c, NetPrice__c From ProposalSummaryGroups__r where LineType__c = 'Grand Total' ), Quoting_Country__r.Rounding_Method__c  From Proposal__Proposal__c in :trigger.new ];
        system.debug('####Check currentSummaryGroups : '+currentProposalList);
        for (Proposal__Proposal__c proposal : currentProposalList) {
            system.debug('####Check  -  Before Net : '+proposal.ProposalSummaryGroups__r[0].NetPrice__c);           

            proposal.ProposalSummaryGroups__r[0].NetPrice__c   =  proposal.ProposalSummaryGroups__r[0].NetPrice__c +100; 

            system.debug('####Check  -  After Net : '+proposal.ProposalSummaryGroups__r[0].NetPrice__c);           

            updateList.add(current);
        }
        if(updateList.size()>0) update updateList;


         }catch(Exception e){} 
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not valid syntax:

```
SELECT ... FROM Proposal__Proposal__c in :trigger.new
```

Instead, you likely want to filter based on `Id`:

```
SELECT ... FROM Proposal__Proposal__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new
```

Also, your code uses one of the worst patterns you could possibly implement: to wrap your entire code in a `try`/`catch`, especially with an empty `catch` block. ***Never implement an empty `catch` block.***